# How to find the first uppercase letter of a word in vim?

Tags: vim

e. g.
`applicatonLoader`
`unixHater`

I want to find 'L' in `applicationLoader`,
or 'H' in `unixHater`.

Comment: https://github.com/bkad/CamelCaseMotion

Comment: What do you want want to do with it? The approach might change depending on what you want.

Comment: one usecase: change first 'word' in camel case word. var [CURSOR]camelCase; to change camel or delete it -> c[first occurance of uppercase letter] or: var camel[CURSOR]InnerCase -> c[first occurance of uppercase {C}]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could search for `\u`:

```
/\u
```

Then use `n` to jump to the next occurrence. Note that this matches all capitals, not just the first in the word.

Edit:
If you only want to jump to the first Capital in words, such as the `E` in `oneExampleCase` and skip the rest in the word, you could search for:

```
/\u\w*
```